# composer require - изменить версию php

Tags: php, composer, php.ini

Пытаюсь установить какие-то модули через composer.

После того, как ввожу название версии для установки, выводится ошибка, сообщая о том, что текущая версия php ниже версии, которую требует модуль для работы.

У нас сайт работает на php7, хотя при из консоли, при использовании команды php -v
показывает версию 5.3

Как я могу настроить, чтобы по умолчанию через консоль тоже php была 7 версии?

Comment: Использоать команду php7 вместо php или типа того?

Comment: Чтобы PHP была версмии 7.0 нужно всего лишь поставить PHP нужной версии. 
Или обратиться к экстрасенсам, которые узнают какой у вас дистрибутив. Ну или если вы скажете что у вас винда, то тут даже экстрасенс не поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Выбрать версию для cli

В gentoo

```
eselect php set cli php7.2
```

В debian/ubuntu

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```